# How to host kmz file for Google Earth Pro network link

Tags: overlay, image, kmz, google-earth-pro

I have a repository consisting of a large number of image overlays, polygons, and 3d polygons in Google Earth Pro. The image overlays are linked to and stored on a windows web server and it works fine if I save as a kmz or kml to send to others. New image overlays will be added and edited over time and colleagues need to have access to the most up to date version.

I want to have the repository saved as a kml or kmz on the web and share a network link with my colleagues instead of sending them a new kmz file each time it's updated. I tried saving it as a kml and kmz on the same web server and pasting the url in as the Network Link, yet nothing loads.

Everything loads if I set the file path to the web server via the network drive, just not as a link. Tried hosting the file as an attachment on Google sites but it was not a valid attachment type.

How can I host this kmz somewhere on the web and access it via Network Link in Google Earth Pro? Believe I'm married to Google Earth Pro because of support for 3D polygons.